# Golang код не выполняется параллельно

Tags: многопоточность, golang, распараллеливание, parallelstream

Функция использует спарсенный текст, чтобы сгенерировать на его основе массив уникальных текстов с помощью метода shuffle.
С использованием горутин и каналов время выполнения программы - 19 сек. Без их использования - 19 сек. То есть я делаю вывод, что что-то где-то блочится. В чем может быть проблема?

```
const generateThreadsNum = 1000

func shuffle(arr *[]string, ch *chan []string) error {
lenArr := len(*arr)
max := big.NewInt(int64(lenArr - 1))
shuffledArr := make([]string, lenArr)
copy(shuffledArr, *arr)
for range shuffledArr {
    randIndex, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, max)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    randNum := int(randIndex.Int64())
    num := shuffledArr[randNum]
    shuffledArr = append(shuffledArr[:randNum], shuffledArr[randNum+1:]...)
    shuffledArr = append(shuffledArr, num)
}
*ch <- shuffledArr
return nil
}

func generateText(Arr *[]string) [][]string {
generatedArr := make([][]string, 0)
ch := make(chan []string, generateThreadsNum)
defer close(ch)
for i := 0; i < generateThreadsNum; i++ {
    go shuffle(Arr, &ch)
}
for {
    unreadData := len(ch)
    if unreadData == generateThreadsNum {
        for i := unreadData; i > 0; i-- {
            generatedArr = append(generatedArr, <-ch)
        }
        break
    }
    runtime.Gosched()
}
return generatedArr
}
func startServer() {
fmt.Println("Server started")
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rawText := multiparseText()
    prettyText := prettifyText(&rawText)
    generatedText := generateText(&prettyText)
    dump, _ := json.Marshal(&generatedText)
    w.Write(dump)
    fmt.Println("Text generated")
})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}

func main() {
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
startServer()
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Параллельным должен быть w.Write, а не все остальное.